# MySQL: Inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, inheritance

I read about an [inheritance feature](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-inherit.html) in PostgreSQL that seemed pretty neat. Unfortunately I am forced to use MySQL. How would you do something similar in a clean way?

Say you for example had the two following classes that you want to work with:

```
User
 ˪ Id
 ˪ Name
 ˪ Password

Employee : User
 ˪ Pay
```

How would you store those in a MySQL database so that they can be fetched from for example PHP in a fairly clean way? I need to for example be able to fetch all users including employees, only employees, find if a user is also an employee, et cetera.

Looking for general advice and not a specific solution to this case. I for example see that I could simply  add a nullable `Pay` column to a `Users` table, but I don't really like that idea as it would quickly become very messy if more sub-classes were needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a field to `Employee` which is a foreign key to `User`. You'd still have to perform a join across the tables, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: So it would sort of be a 1-1 relationship and the `Employees` table would have a `user_id` column or something like that?

Comment: Exact. You could also wrap up the join in a view so that - at least when you read/display your data the two (or more) tables look like one single table to your code.